# How to implement Client Authentication with ServiceStack.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, authentication, servicestack

I am developing web services using the servicestack.net library.

In my scenario, the web services will be called from a WPF application. I need the ability to authenticate that only an approved client app is calling my service.

Is this as simple as hardcoding a "username" and "password" in the client application? This certainly does not seem like the proper approach. Is there a better way?

**EDIT** 
In addition, on the client end, Users themselves will be able to login with a username/password and initiate requests to the service(not sure if this effects anything, so I thought I would mention it),

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For more background information about Authentication in ServiceStack [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865086/how-do-you-implement-authentication-in-servicestack-net/5869158#5869158).

Normally you would authenticate users not clients which you seem to be doing in addition. But if you're trying to lock down services so their only accessible via a specific set of clients you should look into employing some PKI into your client and server.

Basically something along the lines of: the client sends an additional token at login with an encrypted version of the user:password together with a private key embedded in the app. The server has the client public key and so would do un extra validation step on Login to unencrypt the user:pass token and compare it with the validated user credentials.

If a PKI solution is too heavy, an alternate strategy without using encryption could be for clients to ship with a secret Guid which when they login which will send an MD5 hash version of the Guid and the current time, as well as the unhashed version of the time. If the time is within a specified threshold and the MD5 hash is valid then their using an authenticated client.

Comment: Thanks. For now, I think something along the lines of the hashed guid will suffice. Love ServiceStack btw!